# Angular Js ng-disabled the color of the button stays the same whether it is enabled or disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using the angualar js ng-disable functionality to disable a button when it is appropriate.
It is working fine but the user is having a hard time telling if the button is disabled or not since it not totally greyed out. If you hover the cursor over the button you can tell it is disable but the color of the button looks the same as if it were disabled.
Is there a standard style to use that would be more obvious to the user when it becomes disabled. I have not worked with styles very much, so I apologize if it is something obviouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decrease the opacity of the button. Assuming button has a class of disableButton

Also you can add this class 'disableButton' in ng-class specifying the condition you gave for ng-disabled

For the button: (as per your comment)

```
<button data-ng-hide="isDisabled" type="button" ng-class="{'disableButton': isDisabled}" ng-disabled="isDisabled">Submit</button>

<img src="images/image_name.jpg" data-ng-show="isDisabled">
```

CSS:
Also, if you do not want to use the image you can use below CSS to make it more better

```
.disableButton{
    opacity: 0.35; 
    background: #eee;
    color: #444;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found a disable .jpg file that I can use how can I use this other image when it is disabled

Comment: I would not recommend using an image just to show that the button is disabled. Still if you want to use it, check my edit

Comment: I have edited my answer, but I will recommend you to use CSS only

Answer (score 0):

In controller set

```
$scope.isDisabled=true; // when you want to disable the button
```

In button

```
<button type="button" ng-class="{isDisabled ?'Button':'disableButton'}"     ng-disabled="isDisabled" >Submit</button>
```

In Css

```
.disableButton{
background-color:#ffff; }`enter code here`
.Button{
background-image:url('your url of the image'); 
}ter code here
```

Comment: The code will add Button class with background image if the button is not disabled, which is not as per the requirements of the question asked

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="Matter" name="Matter Number" ng-model="MatterNumber" placeholder="Matter Number">



<md-button id="disebledBTN" style="width: 90%; min-width: 100px; background: #338146; color: white; border: 3px; border-radius: 10px; " ng-click="getFilebase64()" ng-disabled="!MatterNumber" ng-style="{ 'background-color' : !MatterNumber ? 'rgb(143 199 158)' : '#338146' }">
 Upload</md-button>
```